# What is the scope of a SOCKET object in Winsock?

Tags: c++, scope, winsock, winsock2

The title pretty much says it all. I'm new to Winsock, and I need to know what the scope of a SOCKET object is.

Do I need to worry about it going out of scope when using it in a class member variable (since when it's returned, it's not dynamic memory)?

Thanks.

<sub><sub>I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no, but since I can't find the info, I figured I would put it out there, for quick reference to others in the future.</sub></sub>

Comment: Winsock, like most of Win32, assumes C and therefore doesn't understand destructors. (COM is the chief exception, which assumes C++ as it was in 1995, but it still doesn't fully understand destructors. )

Comment: @MSalters: COM prefers C++, but also supports C as well.  Destructors don't play into it, it only knows about vtables and reference counts.  Objects destroy themselves however they want when their reference count falls to 0.  A destructor is not strictly required for that.  Commonly used in C++, does not exist in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation for `socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx) says the following:

> When a session has been completed, a `closesocket` must be performed.

And the accompanying sample does just that. The [documentation for `closesocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx) is more forceful:

> An application should always have a matching call to closesocket for each successful call to socket to return any socket resources to the system.

So as long as you keep the `SOCKET` descriptor somewhere you can use it until you call `closesocket`. You could consider putting it inside your own RAII type (or use an existing one) to avoid leaks. If you "forget" the descriptor, you will leak the internal resources.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, SOCKET is just some ID, which is refers to some internal Windows structure. You can work with it like with HANDLE or with usual pointer.

I.e. nothing will happen, if it will go out of scope (but it can leak resources, like HANDLE, if you forgot CloseHandle), if you copy it - you will go 2 same sockets, which are referring to same Windows structure, etc.